# Why is Mimas orbiting Jupiter in In 2010: Odyssey 2?

Tags: 2010-odyssey-two

But why is Saturn's moon Mimas a moon of Jupiter in the book?

> *"Leonov hurtled past the orbits of Io and tiny Mimas"*

I know Saturn was in the original *2001* and not Jupiter, but was this intentional?

Comment: Interestingly, [this wikipedia user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3A2010%3A_Odyssey_Two#Trivia) claims that their copy has a correction - "*My copy says "the orbits of Io and tiny Amalthea", which would be correct. If there was a misprint it's been corrected. 14:04, 12 March 2006 (AEDT)*" but I've checked the most recent ebook version and it still says Mimas.

Comment: I've edited to match the title question and removed a couple of unrelated questions. If you want to know multiple things about the same book, you should [ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) them as separate questions.

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer now, but in brief: the novel and movie of *2001* were developed in parallel, but the location of the latter was switched from Saturn to Jupiter; when 2010 was written it was based on the movie rather than the book.  [More details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010:_Odyssey_Two#Discontinuities_between_2010_and_the_other_works).

Comment: @DavidW I hope you find the time soon.

Comment: In 2010, is the monolith freely orbiting Jupiter along with Discovery and not embedded in a moon?

Comment: Get the book valued and possibly insured if there aren't many.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to either have been an error or a (very odd) misprint. My paperback copy reads:

> *Leonov* hurtled past the orbits of Io and tiny Amalthea.

This was a 1997 printing by Voyager.

Comment: The original editions from the '80s all say Mimas; I've checked the Del Rey (US/International) paperback (1984 and following printings, in this case 5th printing 1989) and the 1983 Granada (UK) paperback.

Comment: Seems like an odd mistake for Clarke to have made - but a very improbable misprint. Lapse by Clarke or an error by an editor?

Comment: @Michael - Interestingly my 2010 'anniversary' ebook edition has the same error.

Comment: @Valorum Presumably a direct reproduction of the original, including any later corrected errors? My edition doesn't specifically mention any significant reworking and I can't find any readily accessible list of changes between editions.

Comment: Thank you guys for the info! That makes much more sense that it was some kind of mistake.......my neurons can rest now!